# Find overlapping dates and exclude them in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is part of my table 'map':
For example, Compare the A and D rows. The A date range is fully within the D date range, so we want to eliminate that row. (I do not want to delete this row, but my query result should not show that row).

```
sed id      code    startdate   enddate
101 1019    A       2002-12-02  2009-11-17 
101 1019    B       1986-01-02  2009-11-04 
101 1019    C       2009-07-01  2009-11-17 
101 1019    C       2002-12-02  2009-06-30 
101 1019    D       1986-01-03  2009-11-17 
101 1019    E       2007-10-15  2009-11-17 
101 1019    E       1992-01-31  1999-08-30 
101 1019    F       2007-11-26  2009-11-05 
101 1019    F       2007-09-05  2007-11-22 
101 1019    F       2007-07-06  2007-09-03
```

Comment: Did you [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap) before posting your question?

Comment: show you desired result

Comment: If two ranges overlap, but one does not completely contain the other, then what happens?  Do you want to combine the ranges?

Answer (score 0):

This would seem to answer your question:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.startdate < t.startdate and t2.enddate >= t.enddate and
                        t2.sed = t.sed and t2.id = t.id and t2.code <> t.code
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks! However I want the opposite. A is contained within D. So, I want to get rid of A. This gets rid of D

Comment: @koala . . . Of course.  I think you want `not exists`.